# facebook graph api getGraphObject()->asArray() returns null

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

so I have this:

`$pages = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/search?q=Computers/Technology&fields=likes'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();`

I just want to get the likes of those pages, so I did `$pages["likes"]` also tried `$pages->likes` and I get null.
But when i do `var_dump($pages)` it shows all the data. So why can't I get just the likes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what var_dump($pages) returns, you may need to do something like $pages[''][''] to get to the likes. I'm not sure since you didn't include that.

If the value isn't undefined and you can actually see the data using var_dump, you shouldn't have any problem getting to the specific fields once you understand the structure. Try

```
print_r($pages)
```

as well to see your info. Also, as long as there's no sensitive data, post the output or a sample of the output to help us with out answers.

Cheers!

Comment: oh thanks! You pointed me to the right direction. I did try something like `['data']['likes']` at first but i looked at it again, it should be `$pages['data'][0]->likes`. So I did a loop for each of those. Thanks!